# Skip adding class name to child element(s) if both parent and child element contains inline background-color

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, domparser

I am trying to add a random class name to elements that contains inline background color. I want to add one more condition to that. If parent and child elements both have inline background color, no need to add class name for child element. Need to skip that specific sub children. How do I skip adding class name for child element if both parent and child element contains background-color?

```js
function modifyContent(content) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
  // select only elements with a style attribute:
  for (const element of doc.querySelectorAll('[style]')) {
    if (element.style.backgroundColor) {
      element.classList.add('someRandomClassName');
    }
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

const input = `<div>
   <div style="font-size :  16px; font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; ">
      <div>
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">Description </span></span></span></span>
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span>
         <br>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
</div>`;
console.log(modifyContent(input));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this selector should work `[style*='background-color']:not([style*='background-color'] [style*='background-color'])`

```js
var modifyContent = function(content) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
  var items = doc.querySelectorAll("[style*='background-color']:not([style*='background-color'] [style*='background-color'])");

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].classList.add("someRandomClassName");
  }

  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

const input = `<div>
   <div style="font-size :  16px; font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; ">
      <div>
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">Description </span></span></span></span>
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span>
         <br>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
</div>`;
const result = modifyContent(input);
console.info(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of what you are asking but here is my take on it. Please note there is **only 1 `<span>` element** in your example that meet your condition, if I understand it correctly (condition being: self and parent have `background-color` style attribute set).

You can verify that with this selector: `doc.querySelectorAll("[style*=\"background-color\"] > [style*=\"background-color\"]")`.

Your code becomes:

```js
var searchItem = function(items, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] === item)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var modifyContent = function(content) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
    
    var items = doc.querySelectorAll("[style*=\"background-color\"]");
    var skip = doc.querySelectorAll("[style*=\"background-color\"] > [style*=\"background-color\"]");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (searchItem(skip, items[i])) {//skip
            items[i].classList.add("skipped");
            console.log("skipped:");
            console.log(items[i]);
        }
        else {//add
            items[i].classList.add("someRandomClassName");
        }
    }
    
     return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

const input = `<div>
   <div style="font-size :  16px; font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; ">
      <div>
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         <span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size">Description </span></span></span></span>
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(254, 255, 102); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family :  Arial,  Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size :  13px; font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; white-space :  normal; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">ncern:&nbsp;</span></span></span></span><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(204, 204, 204); ">Description </span></span></span></span></span><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span><br>
      </div>
      <div><br></div>
      <div><span style="color :  rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style :  normal; font-weight :  400; letter-spacing :  normal; orphans :  2; text-indent :  0px; text-transform :  none; widows :  2; word-spacing :  0px; font-size :  14px; font-family :  LatoRegular,  sans-serif; white-space :  pre-wrap; "><span style="background-color :  rgb(255, 255, 255); " class="x_965909101highlight"><span style="font-family :  tahoma,  arial,  helvetica,  sans-serif,  sans-serif; " class="x_965909101font"><span style="font-size :  13px; " class="x_965909101size"><span class="x_-809421787highlight" style="background-color :  rgb(255, 153, 204); ">
         </span></span></span></span></span>
         <br>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
</div>`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .someRandomClassName {
                border:1px solid red;
            }
            .skipped {
                border:2px solid green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
      
        var result = modifyContent(input);
        /*
          the skipped element(s) are added a ".skipped" CSS class
          for quick visualization
        */
        document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
      });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The span(s) with a green border is/are the skipped element(s).

Comment: Yes. It works with this minimal html data. But failed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uxq2mro9/). I have complex nested html elements. Need to check grandParent and grandChildren also. In this above fiddle it added class name to 4th and 1st span element. It should be added only for 1st span element. Why it is adding class name for grandChildren (I mean 4th span with inline background-color)?

Comment: Expected result should be like this - [Example Screenshot](https://postimg.cc/XrgV0dWj)

Comment: @KaruppiahRK I'm sorry but I don't exactly understand your **condition** for skipping an element. Can you reformulate it more clearly ? Your original post is not clear to me. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: What the purpose of your "randomClass" ? Is it for styling ? Is it for attaching event listeners ? Something else ? :-)

Comment: purpose of `randomClass` to apply CSS filter

Comment: @KaruppiahRK and what is this CSS filter supposed to achieve ?

Comment: To apply invert

Comment: Invert what ? You should give more details if you want a real answer. What is "invert" ? Just styling ? Something else ? You should edit your post and explain what the desired outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

```
hasChildrenBackgroundColor = false;
hasParentBackgroundColor = false;

function modifyContent(content) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
  // select only elements with a style attribute:
  for (const element of doc.querySelectorAll('[style]')) {
    checkChildrenBackgroundColor(element.children);
    
    if (hasParentBackgroundColor && hasChildrenBackgroundColor) {
        hasParentBackgroundColor = false;
        hasChildrenBackgroundColor = false;
      continue;
    }
    
    hasParentBackgroundColor = false;
    hasChildrenBackgroundColor = false;

    if (element.style.backgroundColor) {
      element.classList.add('someRandomClassName');
    }
  }
  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

function checkChildrenBackgroundColor (elements) {
  for (let element of elements) {
        checkParentBackgroundColor(element.parentNode.parentNode);
  
    if (element.style.backgroundColor) {
      hasChildrenBackgroundColor = true;
      return;
    }
  
    if (element.children && element.children.length) {
      checkChildrenBackgroundColor(element.children);
    }
  }
}

function checkParentBackgroundColor (element) {
  if (element && element.style && element.style.backgroundColor) {
        hasParentBackgroundColor = true;
    return;
  }

    if (element.parentNode) {
    checkParentBackgroundColor(element.parentNode);
  }
}
```

Check in the parentElement is the style backgroundColor exists.
Then check in the children collection if some of the elements has the backgroundColor classes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250180/discussion-on-answer-by-dbonev-skip-adding-class-name-to-child-elements-if-bot).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip adding the random class to an element if *any* its child has inline background color, you may use recursion to loop over children:

```js
function modifyContent(content) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");

  for (const element of doc.querySelectorAll("a[style]")) {
    if (element.style.backgroundColor) { // Parent has inline background color
      if (!checkChildren(element)) { // No children have it
        element.classList.add("someRandomClassName");
      }
    }
  }
}

function checkChildren(element) { // Check children recursively
  for (const child in element.children) {
    if (typeof child.style != "undefined") { // Child has property "style"
      if (child.style.backgroundColor) return true; // Child has inline background color
    }

    for (const nestedChild in child.children) { // Checking nested children
      if (checkChildren(nestedChild)) return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: It returns `TypeError: child.style is undefined`

Comment: @KaruppiahRK Updated my answer, try again

Comment: It throws TypeError.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK Updated again

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you're trying to add `filter:invert` for outer most element with style=background-color.

Another css only solution would be

```css
[style*='background-color'] {
  filter: invert(1);
}
[style*='background-color'] [style*='background-color'] {
  /** reset filter for decedents **/
  filter: none;
}

/* OR */

[style*='background-color']:not([style*='background-color'] [style*='background-color']) {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```